# How To Disable Inertia in ScatterView

Tags: wpf, touch, scatterview

Using ScatterView control shipped in Windows Touch WPF. I want to prevent inertia from happening on a scatterview item. But I still want to allow user to move, scale and rotate the item.

So I try this...

```
   ScatterviewItem svi = new ScatterviewItem();
   svi.ManipulationDelta += OnManipulationDelta;
```

...

```
    void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsInertial)
        {
            args.Complete();
            args.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

But the event is never firing.  Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way to do this, or is preventing inertia simply not possible with scatterview?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your event is not firing. Another solution is for you to set the deceleration rate of the ScatterViewItem to a suitably high value.

Answer (score 0):

The event handler is for when the ScatterView is manipulated. Each item added to the ScatterView would need to have the handler set the same way, which you should be able to do by creating a template for the ScatterViewItem class, or if you're using an ItemsControl, through the item template there.

Answer (score 0):

A deceleration rate of 0 will also work

Answer (score 0):

Try using a handler for the `ContainerManipulationDelta` event instead of the `ManipulationDelta` event